# RRAS VPN Issues - Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, subnet, rras

I'm trying to setup a VPN on a new Windows Server 2008 R2 box that is running Hyper-V.

I have setup the VPN using the RRAS and can connect to this VPN from my PC - however I can't access any resources on the Hyper-V host or it's VM's when connected.  Ideally I would like to be able to VPN into the host and access any of my VM's so I don't have to open SQL ports to the world. I assume I must be missing something simple?

Hyper-V Host
 - Roles: Hyper-V, & RRAS

Network:
 - VPN        10.0.0.1/27
 - Hyper-V    203.x.208.69
 - VM 1       203.x.212.145
 - VM 2       203.x.212.146
 - VM 3       203.x.212.147

All computers are part of a work group - no AD at this stage.

Any help would be very much appreciated, networking does my head in.

Thanks,
Glenn

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable LAN routing in the properties of the RRAS server? If not, that's what you need to do.

Comment: How do I achieve this? I don't have enough points to upload images yet :( I have the following options selected in the RRAS Properties window. IPv4 Router - Enabled (LAN & Demand-Dial Routing); IPv4 Routing - Enabled; IPv4 Address Assignment - DHCP; Enable Broadcast Name Resolution - Checked

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't have a RRAS server handy but in the properties of the server you'll find options to enable various routing functions, one of those optins enables LAN routing, which is what you need in order for the VPN clients to access the internal network.